# How to add lighting in my game in java LWJGL?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

How to add lighting in my game in java LWJGL?
I know how to add lighting in C + +, but I do not know how to change it to LWJGL. Can you give me an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the OpenGL C++ API you should be able to do the same in LWJGL. What's the exact problem? Which kind of lighting do you use - built-in via light objects or shaders?

Answer (score 2):

Check out NeHe's tutorial on this: [NeHe tutorial on lighting in openGL](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_filters,_lighting_&_keyboard_control/15002/)
You can download a version for LWJGL at the bottom of that tutorial.